# How to iframe to a next site in array [PHP]

Tags: php, iframe

I have a txt file with website in there :
txt:

```
https://google.com
https://youtube.com
https://facebook.com
```

how to iframe to sites in array 
My code:

```
<?php
$site = $_GET['s'];
$nfile = "fsite.txt";
$file = fopen($nfile, "r");
$wdata = fread($file, filesize($nfile));
$list_site = explode("\n", $wdata);
echo "<iframe src='".$site."' width='100%' height='500px'  >
</iframe>
<br>
<a href='myscripts.php?s=".next($list_site)."'>Next</a>
";
?>
```

but when it iframe to the 2 site the link will not link to the 3 site but it will link to 2 site so how to fix that ?

**EDIT:**
I have found a solution:

```
<?php
$s = $_GET['s'];
$nfile = "fsite.txt";
$file = fopen($nfile, "r");
$wdata = fread($file, filesize($nfile));
$list_site = explode("\n", $wdata);
$next = $s+1;
echo "<iframe src='".$list_site[$s]."' width='100%' height='500px'  >
</iframe>
<br>
<a href='myscripts.php?s=".$next."'>Next</a>
";
?>
```

Comment: You need to advance in the array first until it matches `$site` (or use an index, aka the next key)

Comment: undefined index 3 at line 8 :) when you reach the last site(based on you example, facebook) value of $next would be 3. your list do not have index 3 so it will produce error.

Comment: add something that will check if it reaches the undefined index then set it back to 0 or the first site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Nguyen Viet Hung. I assume that you are in the second page (https://youtube.com). The next page should be https://facebook.com.

The first, you should specify the currently page index. Using array_search and trim to get index of current page. If next page index is out of array, the next page should be the first page.

```
$site = $_GET['s'];
$nfile = "fsite.txt";
$file = fopen($nfile, "r");
$wdata = fread($file, filesize($nfile));
$list_site = explode("\n", $wdata);
$nextIndex = array_search(trim($site), $list_site) + 1;
if($nextIndex > count($list_site)){
    $nextIndex = 0;
}
echo "<iframe src='".$site."' width='100%' height='500px'  >
</iframe>
<br>
<a href='myscripts.php?s=".$list_site[$next]."'>Next</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much :3

Comment: I have just updated my answer. Please check it carefully

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $site = $_GET['s'];
  $nfile = "fsite.txt";
  $file = file($nfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);  //read the list of sites
  $current_site_index = array_search($site, $file); //get the current viewed site's index in the file
  $current_site = $file[$current_site_index];       //get the current viewed site
  $next_site = (isset($file[$current_site_index + 1])) ? $file[$current_site_index + 1] : $file[0]; //get the next site
  echo "<iframe src='$current_site_index' width='100%' height='500px'></iframe><br/><a href='myscripts.php?s=$next_site'>Next</a>"; //display in iframe
?>
```

Comment: That will show all the three. I guess he wants to advance

Comment: No I want it display just 1 site and when I click next it will frame the next site in txt file